# RoR search using dropdowns and checkboxes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This should be relatively simple, and I'm probably overthinking this, but I can't figure it out. Time to call S.O. in for help. First, the bulleted list of what I'm trying to accomplish, then the code.

- I have 8 DB tables, 1 "venue", 7 "days of the week" (Monday, Tues, etc)
- Individual "venues" have an "area" column, as well as a ton of other columns
- I have 3 dropdown menus, the first of which is used to select an "area", the second to select a "day of the week", the third to select an "hour" on the "day of the week" table.
- There are also several checkboxes I'm using to return all results which match whatever is checked (I've got this part figured out, basically, since all the data is within the "venue" table).
- These dropdowns and checkboxes are within a form in application.html.erb
- Ideally, a user should be able to select ONLY an area, and return all results, and leave the other dropdowns blank, OR select ONLY a day of the week, and leave the others blank, etc
- All results should list on venues#index

Alright, now time for the disaster - the code.

venue controller

```
def index
  case 
  when params[:area]
    @venues = Venue.where(:area => params[:area])
  when params[:day]
    @venues = Venue.where(:day => params[:day])
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(venues_path, :method=>:get, id: "search-form") do |f| %>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <%= select_tag "area", options_for_select([ " ", "Area 1", "Area 2" ], params[:area]), {:class=>"styled-select"} %>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
        <%= select_tag "day", options_for_select([ " ", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"], params[:day]), {:class=>"styled-select"} %>
    </div> 
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <%= select_tag "day", options_for_select([[" ", " "], ["3pm", "t1500"], ["4pm", "t1600"], ["5pm", "t1700"], ["6pm", "t1800"], ["7pm", "t1900"], ["8pm", "t2000"], ["9pm", "t2100"], ["10pm", "t2200"], ["11pm", "t2300"], ["12am", "t0000"], ["1am", "t0100"], ["2am", "t0200"], ["3am", "t0300"], ["4am", "t0400"], ["5am", "t0500"], ["6am", "t0600"], ["7am", "t0700"], ["8am", "t0800"], ["9am", "t0900"], ["10am", "t1000"], ["11am", "t1100"], ["12pm", "t1200"], ["1pm", "t1300"], ["2pm", "t1400"]]), {:class=>"styled-select", id: "t", name: "t"} %>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button data-style="expand-right" data-size="s" type=submit class="button">Submit</button>
<% end %>
```

venue model (omitted since I haven't really modified it other than adding nested attributes for new venues - which are working). I'll post it if I need to.

So like I said, I've been racking my brain on this and I can't figure out how to build the correct query/filter to get the results. Am I just approaching this all wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Is your code working at all? Also since this is the `index` action, what happens when neither case is true? I was taught it was good practice to always have a final `else` in a case statement.

Comment: Take a look at the **has_scope** gem.

Comment: Sure.

Basically, I'm trying to get @venues to filter based on whichever dropdown value is selected, or a combination of all three dropdowns, or only two, etc. These should work in any combination.

 - Ideally, a user should be able to select ONLY an area, and return all results, and leave the other dropdowns blank, OR select ONLY a day of the week, and leave the others blank, etc.


Additional complexity - due to the fact that "day of the week" is a separate table(s) entirely. I'm not sure how to query against a different table within the model/controller or form for that matter.

Comment: It is possible with scopes to write something like this: `Venue.joins(:day).merge( Day.monday)` where monday is a scope on day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at model scopes and write something like this:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'has_scope'
```

Model:

```
scope :area, -> q { where area: q }
scope :day, -> q { where day: q }
```

And in your controller:

```
has_scope :area, :day

def index
  @venues = apply_scopes(Venue)
end
```

Haven't tested it, but you need something like this for sane scope filters.

Also check: [Rails guides - active recurd querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: I'll give this a shot